# MYSQL JOIN the same table + COUNT to determine the ranking

Tags: mysql, join

I have a table RANKINGS containing several userIds, associated with a genreId and a ranking related to that genre.

As a benchmark, I will use userId = 30520, but the table contains a lot of records.

```
userId    genreId    ranking
30520     0          135
30520     13         91
30520     24         163
```

It's easy to manually calculate the position of userId, e.g. for the last record:

```
SELECT COUNT(ranking) as position
FROM rankings
WHERE genreId = 24
AND ranking >= 163
ORDER BY ranking DESC
```

With this manual approach, I get:

```
userId    genreId    ranking    position
30520     0          135        5
30520     13         91         17
30520     24         163        7
```

But I can't imagine how this can be achieved with one single query. My try:

```
SELECT userId, a.genreId, COUNT(a.ranking) as position,
FROM rankings a
LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT genreId, ranking
    FROM rankings
    WHERE userId = 30520
) b
ON a.genreId = b.genreId
AND a.ranking >= b.ranking
ORDER BY a.ranking DESC
```

I get only one row:

```
userId    genreId    position
30520     0          3741
```

Thank you for any hint!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add group by into your query:

```
SELECT userId, a.genreId, COUNT(a.ranking) as position
FROM rankings a
LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT genreId, ranking
    FROM rankings
    WHERE userId = 30520
) b
ON a.genreId = b.genreId
AND a.ranking >= b.ranking
GROUP BY genreId
ORDER BY a.ranking DESC
```